# cygwin - gcc compiler installation

Tags: cygwin

I have installed cygwin on my Windows 7 platform. I now wish to access gcc. When I type man gcc, there is no gcc. When I search the downloaded folder for cygwin, I have a folder cygwin\x86_64\release\gcc and two other folders libgcc1 and libstdc++6; each folder has a tar file.

How do I install gcc please?

Comment: Install gcc using the cygwin setup.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction for the usage of cygwin setup are here:

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

By default the setup installs only the packages in the `Base` Category, that are 36
plus some libraries needed by them.
Any of the remaining ~ 8000 packages must be installed directly or could come as dependency of installed packages.

The package that contains the gcc compiler can be found with cygcheck

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/gcc.exe
Found 6 matches for bin/gcc.exe
gcc-core-7.3.0-1 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-core-7.3.0-2 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-core-7.3.0-3 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-debuginfo-7.3.0-1 - gcc-debuginfo: Debug info for gcc
gcc-debuginfo-7.3.0-2 - gcc-debuginfo: Debug info for gcc
gcc-debuginfo-7.3.0-3 - gcc-debuginfo: Debug info for gcc
```

so you need to install `gcc-core`

Comment: I ran cygcheck and my results are exactly as you have shown.  How do I install gcc-core please?

Comment: I removed cygwin and started again. I took the time to study the setup and located the files needed and now the gcc (and other goodies) are being installed.

Comment: No need to remove the installation. Setup allows to add, update, remove the various packages

Comment: I found that out after the event!

Comment: depending the 32 or 64 bit version: https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe  https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe